# AWS architecture - traffic mirroring

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, migration, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-api-gateway

We are going to migrate our database from Aurora Serverless to Aurora Cluster. Before that, we'd like to test the performance of the new database in a real-time traffic scenario. We have thought about cloning the current API Gateway, targeting the new database and mirroring traffic from the production API to the test API.

Is this crazy? Is there any way to achieve this without affecting the performance of the production API Gateway? (there is a CloudFront in front of our API Gateway) Maybe listen for API Gateway events in Cloudwatch and trigger a lambda to run the query against the test API gateway?

Comment: I wonder if you'd be better off with a load testing tool set up for a production-like mix of traffic, or keeping very good logs of API gateway and replaying them with some custom solution. EC2 has traffic mirroring ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html ) but I don't know of any other easy way to do this. I'm not sure you need to both, since you already use Aurora, you're just using a variety where the primary difference is a different scaling method.

Comment: Hi @Tim, finally we are going to abandon this idea and make load testing with HammerDB. Thank you.

Comment: I will make my comment an answer so you can close the question off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you'd be better off with a load testing tool set up for a production-like mix of traffic, or keeping very good logs of API gateway and replaying them with some custom solution.

EC2 has [traffic mirroring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html) but I don't know of any other easy way to do this.

I'm not sure you need to do this, since you already use Aurora, you're just using a variety where the primary difference is a different scaling method.